# expand animation issue of the last item in ListView android

Tags: android, listview

I apply the expand animation in ListView using,

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {

        // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

        // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

    // Making sure we didn't run the ending before (it happens!)
    } else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginEnd;
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        if (mIsVisibleAfter) {
            mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mWasEndedAlready = true;
    }
}
```

Here, when I try to click the last item of the ListView, the last item of my Listview expand downward so, I cannot see the whole contents of the last one without scrolling upward.

In other words, If I click the last one, I want my focus on the bottom side of the last item (automatically scrolling) so I can see the full contents of the last one immediately.

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:(First check if the user has clicked the last item)

```
listView.setSelection(ListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
```

Or sometimes you have to do something like this:

```
listView.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        listView.setSelection(ListAdapter.getCount() - 1);                                                                  
    }
});
```

Comment: Where I trying to do this is extends Fragment, not ListActivity. So I cannot use setSelection method. Is there any other way I can try?

Comment: Yes, but... when I try, program says, "The method setSelection(int) is undefined for the type PullToRefreshListView"

Comment: Oh! so you are using a custom listview library that is why you can't find that method, would you check and tell me which android view does your PullToRefreshListView extends?

Comment: PullToRefreshListView extends PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase<ListView> PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase<T extends AbsListView> extends PullToRefreshBase<T>    PullToRefreshBase<T extends View> extends LinearLayout ; so is it finally extends the linearlayout?

Comment: Ok so that is the problem, your ListView ultimately extends LinearLayout that is why there is no such method, let me check if i get my hands on something useful, and i think you should check all the methods that the library provides, maybe there is some method with similar functionality

Comment: Maybe you can refer this library https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this problem without using the given library? because I make the project almost, and i think that in this way, I have to make the whole inflating procedure of the project again.

Comment: As far as i know, either you can check the methods provided to you by your library or check your library's java file for a workaround.